# Failed to download files from a remote machine using MobaXterm

Tags: ssh, sftp, mobaxterm

I am connected to a local VM linux machine using MobaXterm SSH with no problems. The problem is I am not able to download files from that machine. MobaXterm shows that dowloading is in progress, but never ends. MobaXterm log says that "the connection is closed by a lower level protocol". 
What does this mean? Any suggestions how to solve it?

Thanks in advance
Dhiaa Eddin Anabtawi

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the ssh settings.

In MobaXterm, go to Home->Sessions->UserSessions->*right click on* your ssh session->Edit Session

Once you're there, go to SSH -> Advanced SSH Settings, and change SSH-browser type to SCP(normal speed) or SCP(enhanced speed). I personally thinks the first option it's better.
Finally, restart your session and try to download now.

P.D: if you had SCP activated, try to do it backwards: change to STFP protocol.